# UISearchController SearchBar Overlapping Status Bar and Whitespace

Tags: uisearchcontroller

I have a view controller with a search button as the navigation item's right bar button item. When the search button is pressed, I want the a UISearchController to be presented. Here is the relevant code:

```
@interface BaseViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *searchBarButtonItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *accountBarButtonItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableViewController *searchResultsController;

@end

@implementation BaseViewController

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        UIImage *accountIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"account-male-icon@2x.png"];

        UIBarButtonItem *accountBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:accountIcon style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(accountButtonPressed:)];
        UIBarButtonItem *searchBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(searchButtonPressed:)];

        [self setSearchResultsController:[[UITableViewController alloc] init]];
        [self setSearchController:[[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:[self searchResultsController]]];

        [[[self searchResultsController] tableView] setDataSource:self];
        [[[self searchResultsController] tableView] setDelegate:self];
        [[[self searchResultsController] tableView] setTableHeaderView:[[self searchController] searchBar]];

        [[self searchController] setSearchResultsUpdater:self];
        [[self searchController] setDelegate:self];
        [[self searchController] setHidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation:YES];
        [[self searchController] setDimsBackgroundDuringPresentation:YES];
        [[[self searchController] searchBar] setDelegate:self];

        [self setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];

        [self setSearchBarButtonItem:searchBarButtonItem];
        [self setAccountBarButtonItem:accountBarButtonItem];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:[self accountBarButtonItem]];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[self searchBarButtonItem]];
}

- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:[self searchController] animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When the search button is pressed, the searchController gets presented. All is well, except the following two things occur:

1.) The search bar overlaps the status bar

2.) There is white space in the first row of the table view

Below are pictures illustrating the problem:

[image]

[image]

How do I resolve the status bar issue and remove the white space in the first row?

Comment: I solved the problem. I had to remove the line of code: `[[[self searchResultsController] tableView] setTableHeaderView:[[self searchController] searchBar]];`

Comment: I am facing the same issue, if I remoce the above line the entire searchbar disppears, where have you added your searchbar as a subview?

Comment: any solutions yet @Geet?